# Programatically highlight input tags depending on the state value of redux

Tags: reactjs

I have input values as such

```
                 <input type="text"
                    className="fadeIn second inputValues"
                    name="fullname"
                    placeholder="full name"
                    required
                    value={state.fullname}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler}
                />
                <input type="email"
                    className="fadeIn second inputValues"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="email"
                    required
                    value={state.email}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler} />
```

I want to add `border-danger` to the className of the value i get from redux i.e `error_param`.
eg: `error_param = 'email'` then add border to email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your component manages to get updates from redux and keep it in `email_has_error`:

```js
<input 
     type="email"
     className={`fadeIn second inputValues ${this.state.email_has_error?"err":""}`}
     name="email"
     placeholder="email"
     required
     value={state.email}
     onChange={onChangeHandler} />
```

now you can add your border to `.err` class name in css.